# Connecting from JBoss 4.2 to JBoss 7.1

Tags: jndi, jboss7.x, jboss-4.2.x

We would like to create a completely new service using JBoss 7.1 with modern technologies
such as JPA, Java EE 6, etc....
Alas, we have a legacy system running on a JBoss 4.2.2 that is definitely **NOT** portable to JBoss 7. The old system will have to access the new system, i.e. call methods via RMI.

Unfortunately, that is not possible out of the box:

- JBoss 7 does not support the old JNP protocol anymore that was usually used in JBoss 4 for JNDI lookups.
  (See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI+Reference)
- We cannot just add the new JARs needed for the new protocol to, say, default/lib, because this will cause version conflicts (logging, e.g.) and simply does not work.

I see two possible solutions, which are both complicated and error-prone:

1. We add a new Deployment to JBoss 4 that is packaged with all
   necessary libraries to access JBoss 7 using and try to use  JBoss'
   class loader magic in jboss-app.xml to make it work.
2. We retrofit the old JNP server which can be found in jnpserver.jar
   as a new JBoss 7 module.

In both cases we would have to bind a Bridge/Adapter object to the JNDI context via JNP that forwards all requests.

Does anyone have experiences in bridging the gap (rather a snake pit in fact) between JBoss 4 to JBoss 7 or a better idea?

Thanks in advance.

Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easier and use web services between them as this will also avoid and classloader / serialization hell